# issue returning string from component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx

I have a component in ReactJS that i want to call to only return a string. If i'm within the component itself, i can console the value of the returning object and it does indeed return a string, but when i console the component it returns an object

Page content

```
render(){
<Portrait displayFromAPIID={content.Author._id} returnNameOnly={true}></Portrait>
}
```

This renders the correct output in HTML, but i want to use the output in a meta tag, so i only want the string itself, not the JSX;

Component

```
getNameOnly() {
        let staffMembers = this.selectStaffMembers();
        console.log(Object.values(staffMembers)[2])
        return Object.values(staffMembers)[2];
    }
render() {
        const name = this.getNameOnly();
        if(this.state.returnNameOnly === true){
            return name
        }
    }
```

I want to use this component as it stores all our user values, but i can't seem to pass the content through to another component, as it just recognises it as a component. FYI, i jsut this component to return lots of different things, so i don't want to change the component overall, just want the output of this specific return to be a string only

```
<meta name="author" content="[object Object]" data-react-helmet="true">
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Having the same issue, did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well you problem but the output of a component is always going to be a React element. 
If you need to extract some data from it maybe you can create a static method to extract it. But to be honest, it seems that maybe you need to store this data somewhere else.